# C# Accessing Inherited members via parent class in a 3D List

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, list

Ok this is hard to explain, but here goes.
I have a 3D list of objects. The objects type are called CObject, another class CTile inherts CObject.

```
       static public List<List <List <CObject>>> CObjList 
                  = new List<List<List<CObject>>>();
```

Ok now lets say that the list is full of information in the correct way. (Can be see via breakpionts in the code);
So I go to access an item in list like below

```
CObjList.[0][0][0].titleImageId
```

Ok titleImageId is a member of CTile, but I cant access it by using this syntax. Its public and everything.
All that I can access are the members of CObject class.

I hope I have explained myself as best I can there. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((CTile)CObjList[0][0][0]).titleImageId
```

or

```
(CObjList[0][0][0] as CTile).titleImageId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
CList l = CObjList[0][0][0] as CList;
if(l != null)
    id = l.titleImageId
```

You should index the `CObjList` directly, not using a dot operator